# Converting Latex Files to Blog Posts

Tags: latex

What is the best way to convert latex files to blog posts?  I'm aware that there are ways of getting simple latex formulas to show up in certain blog services (blogger, wordpress, etc.), but is there a way to take a latex file and place it into a blog with minimal effort?

Comment: There are quite a few tools that will convert TeX/LaTeX to HTML. I think most of them are aimed at producing entire Web pages, rather than "blog-friendly" snippets. I also think most of them are geared towards command-line use, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc might help, as it converts basic LaTeX to HTML as well as Markdown, e.g. `pandoc -s to-be-blogged.tex -o blogpost.md`. It's in the repositories of most Linux distros.